# LDAP Joomla using JMapMyLDAP

Tags: joomla, ldap

I am really bad at understanding LDAP and I have not found a reliable source to learn what I need about it. I need now to authenticate users in joomla using an LDAP directory, and I am using [JMapMyLDAP](http://shmanic.com/tools/jmapmyldap/about.htm). In the configuration it asks me for a base DN and I am not sure what that is but in this case I have

```
ou=People,do=uniandes,do=edu,do=co
```

and then in filter, I would like to filter by Uid, I want to be able to map the users by Uid so that depending on their uid I can assign them the appropriate viewing and editing permissions and I am not quite sure how to do it so in filter I have

```
(&(uid=[username]))
```

Then in lookup type I have -forward- In lookup attribute I have -member- and in lookup member I have -Uid- and in DN attribute -distinguishedName-. Finally I have the mapping as myusername:group and when trying to log with my LDAP user I just cant log in. I don't know if I am doing something wrong or what may be happening. Any one has any idea? Any suggested reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What LDAP directory are you using.  Your base DN of `ou=People,do=uniandes,do=edu,do=co` is almost certainly incorrect.  The `cn=`, `ou=`, `dc=` part are well known naming attributes of objects.  `do=` seems very unlikely.

If you are using Active Directory as your LDAP directory, the last part (Usually two) need to `dc=`.

Far more likely is `ou=People,dc=uniandes,dc=edu` unless the last bit about `do=co` means something in your context.

If you are using eDirectory as an LDAP directory, far more likely is: `ou=People,ou=uniandes,o=edu`

As for your filter of `(&(uid=[username]))` you can probably get by with just `(uid=[username])` assuming the `[username]` is a Joomla macro for the username provided.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really don't know which LDAP is used here. I started working for a university in Colombia, hence the "co". Do you know a way to find out what kind of LDAP is being used?

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy Well, the `do=co` then makes sense in the second half.  However, I cannot think of what `do=` could mean.  Usually it is the naming attribute of an object class.  I do not think those are localized.  Can you ask the admins of the LDAP system what they are using?  Social engineering and all that jazz.

Answer (score 1):

For example:
      labs.com

/ \

login     company

/ \        / \

user group unit customer

/  |  \

mis account hr

root-unit.ldif:

## root node

dn: dc=labs,dc=com

dc: labs

objectClass: dcObject

objectClass: organizationalUnit

ou: labs Dot com

## login top

dn: ou=login,dc=labs,dc=com

ou: login

objectClass: organizationalUnit

## user, uid, password

dn: ou=user,ou=login,dc=labs,dc=com

ou: user

objectClass: organizationalUnit

## group

dn: ou=group,ou=login,dc=labs,dc=com

ou: group

objectClass: organizationalUnit

### for company organization top

dn: ou=company,dc=labs,dc=com

ou: company

objectClass: organizationalUnit

## for company organization (unit)

dn: ou=unit,ou=company,dc=labs,dc=com

ou: unit

objectClass: organizationalUnit

## human resource (under unit)

dn: ou=hr,ou=unit,ou=company,dc=labs,dc=com
ou: hr
objectClass: organizationalUnit

## MIS (under unit)

dn: ou=mis,ou=unit,ou=company,dc=labs,dc=com
ou: mis
objectClass: organizationalUnit

## Account (under unit)

dn: ou=account,ou=unit,ou=company,dc=labs,dc=com

ou: account

objectClass: organizationalUnit

## for customers information

dn: ou=customer,ou=company,dc=labs,dc=com

ou: customer

objectClass: organizationalUnit

[refernce](http://iori.tw/ldap%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%9D%E5%8F%8A%E6%95%B4%E5%90%88%E7%99%BB%E5%85%A5%E8%AA%8D%E8%AD%89%E6%A9%9F%E5%88%B6%E7%9A%84%E6%9E%B6%E8%A8%AD-on-centos-6-2_x64/)